# Flutter Custom Graphics

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to create something like this in Flutter. That gradient green line in a circle that looks like a progress indicator. The circle remains stills but spins sometimes.

[image]

Any ideas on where to start or are there libraries out there to help me out?

Comment: use a `CustomPaint` widget - your drawing code will be implemented by a class that extends `CustomPainter`

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://www.2dimensions.com/, its a website for building very complex animations the can be exported to flutter.
and theres https://lottiefiles.com/ which pretty much does the same
there both very good and supply what you need